# Finding out when Recursion involving Asynchronous operation finishes

Tags: actionscript-3, recursion, air

I have a recursive call which includes an asyn operation (file copy) ..
I want to find out when the recursive call finishes (along with all asyn operations).

```
    private function copyInto(directoryToCopy:File, locationCopyingTo:File):void
        {
          var directory:Array = directoryToCopy.getDirectoryListing();
          //get list of files in dir 

          for each (var f:File in directory)
          {
            if (f.isDirectory)
              copyInto(f, locationCopyingTo.resolvePath(f.name));
            else
             {
               f.copyToAsyn(locationCopyingTo.resolvePath(f.name), true);
               f.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFilecopied);
              }
          }    
        }

function onFileCopied(event){ 
    alert(event.target); // [object File] 
}
```

Basically what I needed was to copy a folder structure to another drive,and the folder 
being copied contains some files that are 100-200MB and which take time to copy,which 
blanks out the UI and the flash player.
And after the files get copied, I want to do further things(hopefully without 
blocking the UI).

Any help?

Thanks All .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count the calls of `copyToAsync` and use a wrapper function like `doCopy` in my example.

```
private var copyCount: int = 0;
private var isCopying: Boolean = false;

public function doCopy(directoryToCopy:File, locationCopyingTo:File):void
{
    isCopying = true;
    try {
      copyInto((directoryToCopy, locationCopyingTo);
    finally {
      isCopying = false;
    } 
}

private function copyInto(directoryToCopy:File, locationCopyingTo:File):void {
    var directory:Array = directoryToCopy.getDirectoryListing();

    for each (var f:File in directory) {
        if (f.isDirectory)
            copyInto(f, locationCopyingTo.resolvePath(f.name));
        else {
            copyCount++; 
            f.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileCopied);
            f.copyToAsync(locationCopyingTo.resolvePath(f.name), true);
        }
    }    
}

function onFileCopied(event: Event): void
{ 
    copyCount--;
    if (copyCount == 0 && !isCopying)
        trace("finished");
}
```

**Important:** The `isCopying` flag checks if the `copyInto` function is still running, otherwise you could run into to a condition where `copyCount == 0`, but the copying is not finished.

Answer (score 1):

You could set a static class-level counter of files to be copied that increments when you find another file to copy, and decrements when the event function signals that the copy has ended.

```
private static fileCounter:int = 0;
```

and in the loop:

```
++fileCounter;
f.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFilecopied);
f.copyToAsync(locationCopyingTo.resolvePath(f.name), true);
```

and in the event handler:

```
function onFileCopied(event)
{ 
    if ( --fileCounter == 0 )
        trace("finished");
}
```

But is weak because you can't recover from errors, nor know which files have been copied. To build a more robust solution you could store not only a counter of files but a list of file names in a class:

```
class FileCopyInfo
{
...
    private var fileName:String;
    private var finished:Boolean;
}
```